# trigger is not working properly

Tags: mysql

I have create trigger for some condition but its through error.

Here is trigger code.

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `getcrm`.`update_round_date` AFTER UPDATE ON `getcrm`.`vtiger_stockcheckcf`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
    DECLARE retribAn INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
  DECLARE curEdate datetime;     
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE curTipo CURSOR FOR
          SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM vtiger_crmentity AS a, vtiger_stockcheck AS b,vtiger_stockcheckcf AS c WHERE a.crmid = b.stockcheckid AND a.crmid = c.stockcheckid AND c.cf_746 = 'Pending' AND a.setype='StockCheck';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
  OPEN curTipo;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curTipo INTO retribAn;
    IF NOT done THEN       
    set curEdate = NOW();
    IF a.createdtime = curEdate AND c.cf_746 = Pending THEN 
    INSERT INTO vtiger_cancellationcf(scheckid,cf_1150,cf_1152,cf_1154,cf_1156,cf_1151,cf_1153,cf_1155,cf_1157,cf_1158,cf_1160,cf_1162,cf_1159,
cf_1161,cf_1163,cf_1203,cf_1178,cf_1180,cf_1182,cf_1184,cf_1186,cf_1178,cf_1180,cf_1182,cf_1184,cf_1186,cf_1179,cf_1181,
cf_1183,cf_1185,cf_1187,cf_1179,cf_1181,cf_1183,cf_1185,cf_1187,cf_1164,cf_1166,cf_1168,cf_1170,cf_1165,cf_1167,cf_1169,
cf_1171,cf_1173,cf_1176,cf_1177,cf_1172,cf_1174,cf_1175,cf_1188,cf_1189,cf_1190) values ('a.crmid','"c.cf_709"','"c.cf_711"','"c.cf_713"','"c.cf_715"','"c.cf_710"','"c.cf_712"','"c.cf_714"',
'"c.cf_716"','"c.cf_717"','"c.cf_719"','"c.cf_721"','"c.cf_718"','"c.cf_720"','"c.cf_844"','"c.cf_1079"','"c.cf_736"',
'"c.cf_738"','"c.cf_740"','"c.cf_742"','"c.cf_744"','"c.cf_737"','"c.cf_739"','"c.cf_741"','"c.cf_743"','"c.cf_745"',
'"c.cf_722"','"c.cf_724"','"c.cf_726"','"c.cf_723"','"c.cf_725"','"c.cf_727"','"c.cf_729"','"c.cf_731"','"c.cf_734"',
'"c.cf_735"','"c.cf_730"','"c.cf_732"','"c.cf_733"','"b.stockcheck"','"c.cf_746"','"c.cf_1080"','"c.cf_1081"');

insert into vtiger_cancellation (cancellationid,cancellation,scheckid) values ('a.crmid',' ','c.cf_709');
insert into vtiger_crmentity (crmid,smcreatorid,smownerid,modifiedby,setype,description,createdtime,modifiedtime,viewedtime,status,version,presence,deleted,label) values ('a.crmid','a.smcreatorid','a.smownerid','a.smcreatorid','Cancellation','','curEdate','curEdate','','','0','1','0','');
delete FROM vtiger_crmentity_seq where id='a.crmid';
insert into vtiger_crmentity_seq (id)values ('a.crmid');
END IF;
END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE curTipo;    
end
//
DELIMITER
```

Here is error when any changes on table.
1328 - Incorrect number of FETCH variables

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 4):

That is simply a syntax error and the message you are getting is telling you exactly what is wrong.

In your cursor definition you are selecting out many columns (all from each of the three tables) and in the fetch statement you are only referring to a single column (pulling the first column from the cursor into the variable retribAn). The number of variables you fetch from the cursor needs to match the number the cursor returns.